# Modifying InBook Reference with Chicago-Annote style

Tags: chicago-style, custom-bib

I have this inbook refrence:

```
@InBook{Buck2012,
chapter       = {1},
pages         = {1--24},
title         = {Chemistry, Properties, and Uses of Commercial Fluorinated Surfactants},
publisher     = {Springer},
year          = {2012},
author        = {Buck, Robert C. and Murphy, Peter M. and Pabon, Martial},
editor        = {Knepper, Thomas P. and Lange, Frank T.},
address       = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
booktitle     = {Polyfluorinated Chemicals and Transformation Products},
groups        = {Basics, Uses},
}
```

Currently my citation style produced that output:

> Buck, R. C., P. M. Murphy, and M. Pabon (2012). *Chemistry, Properties, and Uses
>   of Commercial Fluorinated Surfactants*, Chapter 1, pp. 1-24. Berlin, Heidelberg:
>   Springer.

but I actually want to have this:

> Buck, R. C., P. M. Murphy, and M. Pabon (2012). Chemistry, Properties, and Uses
>   of Commercial Fluorinated Surfactants. In: Knepper, T. P. and Lange, F. T. (eds.) *Polyfluorinated Chemicals and Transformation Products,* Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, pp. 1-24.

I am working with the Chicage Annote Style from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chicago-annote?lang=de) (I Have made slight modification but they should not influence the inbook referencing.

Does anybody have a suggestion? How to alter the bst-file or sth else? 
Thanks

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but I suspect your entry is actually an `@incollection`. Maybe changing the type already helps a bit.

Comment: yes, perfect! that looks much better. who would have thought that it is so easy?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `@incollection` entry type.

`@inbook` is only for books where each chapter was written by the same set of authors - the book authors. `@incollection` is for collections that normally have an `editor` and where the chapters are normally written by different sets of authors (not necessarily but often) different from the editors of the collection.